# Setting up VPN for satellite locations

Tags: vpn, sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn

I'm looking to set up multiple VPNs to connect 6 different smaller locations all together. I mean to use a site to site VPN from each location to the main location. I'm using Sonicwall TZ210's at each location.

Each center will have a different ip scheme.

```
192.168.1.1-40
192.168.2.1-40
192.168.3.1-40
192.168.4.1-40
192.168.5.1-40
...
...
```

Is this a normal way to go about this? Or is there a more recommended way? I apologize if this is a simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that should work just fine for you. We have a similar set up (only 3 locations though, not 6) and it works great. One thing I will advise, however, is using different subnets. Either go a little higher up than 192.168.1.x or use a 10.x.x.x or 172.168.x.x. I say this because if you ever intend to allow users VPN access from home, it's almost always that they'll have either 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x as their IP range at home. With that being the case, it causes routing issues when they're connected to the VPN. Unfortunately I speak from experience :) So plan ahead. If you foresee that you'll ever allow your users to use VPN (particularly those at the remote site with the proposed 192.168.1.x subnet) then I'd suggest choosing different subnets.

Comment: ...or just use nat on the connections.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. What you are planning is called a "[Hub and Spoke VPN topology](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=606584&seqNum=3)" since it has a central hub gateway and several VPN endpoints connected like spokes to the hub only. It is quite common, easy to manage and well understood.